# Will the depth be written immediately after Early Z passes?

Tags: opengl, graphics, depth-testing

If not, then why discard interrupted earlyZ?
Imagine that there is an object A in front of B, A has a discard operation in fs.Assume that the pixel of A at screen coordinates (100, 100) pass the Early z test,then it is discarded in the fragment shader,so A has no chance to write depth.Now render B!Obviously A will not have any effect on B at (100,100). If this is the case, then why does A’s EarlyZ need to be interrupted?

Comment: I did not quite get your question, but from what it sounds like, there is also something called **transparency**, that affects how pixels and depth will be discarded / rendered.

Comment: @SnipingPoodle No sorry, but the "transparency" has no effect on the depth of a fragment. The transparency comes into play when you use [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending), but it has nothing to do with the [Depth Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test).

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that.

Comment: @SnipingPoodle I just want to know if early-z is write depth to buffer before FS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the depth write is (as far as the hardware is concerned) part of the depth test. This is a atomic, ordered read/modify/write operation, so the hardware implements it that way.

Therefore, [fragment testing before the fragment shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Early_Fragment_Test#Optimization) also means [writing those fragment values before the fragment shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment#Fragment_discard). So even if the FS discards the fragment, part of its components have already been written and cannot be unwritten.

So if an FS has a `discard` statement in it, the GPU will not use early tests unless the FS specifies that it must do so. And if it does specify that, then the `discard` will only *partially* discard the fragment.

Note that this also includes things like occlusion query counts and stencil tests/writes.